# Être faire quelque chose

Tags: grammaire, usage, verbes, passé-composé

Dans La chambre bleue de Prosper Mérimée on trouve la phrase suivante :

> Le jeune homme [...] avait été reconnaître cet hôtel quelque temps auparavant [...]

Ce "avait été reconnaître" me semble étrange. À la place, je dirais qu'il faut écrire "allait reconnaître" ou quelque chose de même sens :

> Le jeune homme [...] allait reconnaître cet hôtel quelque temps auparavant [...]

En tout cas, je n'ai jamais vu l'expression "être faire quelque chose." Est-ce bien correcte et si oui, est-ce obsolète ?

(À noter qu'en allemand, on peut bien dire "er ist etwas auskundschaften gewesen" ce qui correspond littéralement à "il a été reconnaître quelque chose"... mon espoir que l'expression existe en français est tout à fait fondé sur ce fait.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

« Avoir été » est synonyme d'« être allé », et de même pour tous les temps composés passés du verbe *aller*. La phrase signifie donc « Le jeune homme […] **était allé** reconnaître cet hôtel […]. ».

Cette tournure est familière. Je suis surpris que Mérimée l'utilise (hors éventuellement d'un dialogue) : elle ne correspond pas au niveau de langue qu'utilise par ailleurs le narrateur. Mais je ne vois vraiment pas ce que ce pourrait être d'autre. Le sens colle parfaitement.